# Nested route request interpreted as request for CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-router

Not even sure how to phrase this question.

Basically I have a React application and I'm using React-Router for route handling and a node server to send back the index.html file on every request and handle static assets as I'm using React Router's HistoryLocation configuration. Logging each request to that server, I can see that going to the base url sends 3 requests and everything works just fine:

`GET / 200 3.795 ms - -
GET /static/app.css 200 2.234 ms - -
GET /build/bundle.js 200 0.608 ms - -`

Same goes for any regular shallow route (e.g. `/a`). However, as soon as I try to access a nested route (e.g. `/a/b`), everything breaks. More specifically, in the window, I get a syntax error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, and in my node server's logs, I get these requests:

```
GET /a/b 304 2.286 ms - -
GET /a/static/app.css 304 1.061 ms - -
GET /a/build/bundle.js 304 1.004 ms - -
```

So it seems like the behavior here is everytime I send a page-view request, it sends one request for the given nested route, and for any additional static assets it just pops off the nested route and appends what the route of that static asset is to whatever else is part of that route. So for example if I go to `/a/b/c`, I would see something like `GET /a/b/static/app.css`.

Here's my node server setup:

```
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

const STATIC_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '/../dist');

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(express.static(STATIC_PATH));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: STATIC_PATH });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8000);
app.server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you may have static resource URLs in your web page that are like `"static/app.css"` which is a fully relative URL.  When you do that, the browser makes a request for that filename on the same path as the current web page and it will vary based on the path of the current web page.  So, if your web page is `/a.html`, it will request `/static/app.css`.  If your web page is `/a/b.html`, it will request `/a/static/app.css` (which appears to be what you are seeing).

What you probably want is a domain relative path for the static resource that starts with a leading `/` and looks something like `"/static/app.css"`. The leading slash makes it relative only to the domain, not to the path of the web page. The browser will then make the same request no matter what the path is for your web page because the path is relative to the top of the domain.

So, to summarize, the HTML files get changed from this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/app.css">
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/app.css">
```

Comment: Wow! I'll need to do a little more tinkering to be sure it fixes all my issues involving nested routing, but if nothing else, on my first pass through that does fix all my static asset requests.

To clarify for anyone else: I just had to go into my index.html to prepend a `/` to all my source files. For example, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/app.css">` became  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/app.css">`